# Can not cast list<object> to list<custom object>

Tags: c#, json, list, linq

I have 3 class like below.

```
[Serializable]
public class Classa {
  public list<Object> list {get; set;}
}

[Serializable]
public class Classb {
  public string name {get; set;}
  public string nickname {get; set;}
}


[Serializable]
public class Classc {
  public string type {get; set;}
  public string price {get; set;}
}
```

In my program, I want to cast `List<Object>` to `List<Classb>` or `List<Classc>` when I pass the JSON structure matching with `Classb` or `Classc`... is there any way to cast it?

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Import")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public Object Import([FromBody]Classa ImportData)
{

  List<Classb> blist = a.list.Cast<Classb>().toList();

}
```

It throws:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type
>   'Classb'

I have tried :

```
List<Classb> blist = aOfType<Classb>().ToList();
```

Success but no value..

Comment: Oh.. I fix it myself...  Just Convert to Jarray first will fix it

Answer (score 0):

In Classa you have a list with Objects, but you want a list with Classb. So change this

```
[Serializable]
public class Classa{
list<Object> list{get;set;}
}
```

to

```
[Serializable]
public class Classa{
list<Classb> list{get;set;}
}
```

And this

```
 List<Classb> blist = a.list.Cast<Classb>().toList();
```

Can be

```
List<Classb> blist = a.list;
```

EDIT:
You have a typo her

```
publc class Classb{
```

Comment: I know that's one of solution.. but i have other class  for example  classc.. I want to put it into list<Object> too.. So that I can not change to list<classb> btw thanks you

Comment: If you want to do that, you can let Classa have 2 lists, with Classb and Classc. But if you really want Classa to only have 1 list. You make a new ClassSuper and make Classb and Classc extend from ClassSuper. Classa will than have a list with ClassSuper